# Why adding a element to a set within dictionary, all sets is being modified? (Python)

Tags: python, dictionary, set

I am trying to add an element to a set within a dictionary in Python, but when I use `mydictionary[index].update([newelement])`, all the dictionary is being updated with the newelement. Here goes the python console commands and outputs to demonstrate what I am saying:

```
>>> graph=dict.fromkeys(range(10),set([]))
>>> graph
{0: set([]), 1: set([]), 2: set([]), 3: set([]), 4: set([]), 5: set([]), 6: set([]), 7: set([]), 8: set([]), 9: set([])}
>>> graph[0].update([1])
>>> graph
{0: set([1]), 1: set([1]), 2: set([1]), 3: set([1]), 4: set([1]), 5: set([1]), 6: set([1]), 7: set([1]), 8: set([1]), 9: set([1])}
```

So why isn't updating only the entry for `graph[0]`?

I really tried to find a topic with this question specifically, but I didn't find one.

Obs: The parenthesis with numbers are the commands in python console.

Answer (score 1):

`dict.fromkeys` creates a dictionary with keys from the first item you put in and with values that *are* the second element.  In other words, all of the values are referencing the same object.

This is the same as if:

```
a = set()
b = a
b.add('foo')
print a
```

In this case, you'll see that both `a` and `b` have an element `'foo'`.  Now look at their IDs:

```
print id(a)
print id(b)
```

Notice that it's the same number because they are the same object.

Answer (score 1):

The variable `graph` isn't 10 sets, it's a ten-element dictionary, where each value references the *same* set. Thus, modifying the contents of one set modifies them all.

```
>>> graph=dict.fromkeys(range(10),set([]))
>>> id(graph[0]), id(graph[1])
(140681644256512, 140681644256512)
```